# no animation when using modal segue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, segue

I have a view controller and have a few objects that I have some simply animations hooked up to.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                          delay: 10.1
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         addNameViewConstraint.constant = 10;
                         addNameView.alpha = 1.0;
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];   // move
                     }
                     completion:nil];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                          delay: 0.15
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         addEmailViewConstraint.constant = 10;
                         addEmailView.alpha = 1.0;
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];   // move
                     }
                     completion:nil];
```

When I was using the push segue the animation works fine. But when I switched to using a modal segue the animation stopped working. I increased the delay in the first one to 10.2 seconds thinking that maybe it was animating before I got to see it. I am calling this animation in the viewWillAppear method. Again works if I'm doing a push segue.. but not for modal. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you developing for iOS 7 and not using xibs? Set your modal view's background color to white if yes.

Comment: Try moving the code to `viewDidAppear:` just to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thanks Matt! viewDidAppear did the trick. Any ideas as to why?

jsksma2 - Why would I have to set the modal background to white?

Comment: The main downside to using viewWillAppear is that the animation will not stater until the modal view is in place, before with the push the animation started before the new view controller was in place which made it a much smoother animation. Is there any way of still achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am calling this animation in the viewWillAppear method

This is a common mistake. `viewWillAppear:` is too soon to start the animation. The view has not yet appeared so there is nothing to animate. Move the `animateWithDuration:...` code to `viewDidAppear:` and all will be well.

This is, however, as you say in your comment, insufficiently satisfying. What you are after is that the modal transition should be happening and your extra animations within the new view should already be happening as the modal view is in the process of appearing. Instead, with `viewDidAppear:`, the modal view finishes appearing, it settles into place, and *then* your other animations start, which is not as cool.

One solution might be to move the animations again, this time to `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. This is trickier because this method gets called a lot. You will need to use a BOOL instance variable as a flag to ensure that your animations run only once. Thus, this should work (I tried it and it seemed fine):

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    if (!self->didLayout) {
        self->didLayout = YES;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
            // mess with constraint constants here
            [self.subv layoutIfNeeded];
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matt this works exactly like I want it to. Thank you also for the detailed explanation of what you did as well! Nicely done.